# python3 sys.exit vs SystemExit

Tags: python, python-3.x, nagios

New to Python 3, and running into an issue I'm having trouble debugging. When the status prints using `sys.exit`, the output from my `print` statement gets cut off to one line, but when I use `SystemExit` it prints all of the output. Can anyone explain this to me please?

```
import psutil
import sys

def mountpoint():
    output = psutil.disk_partitions(all=False)
    marray = []
    #create a list from the disk partitions function
    for fs in output:
        marray.append(fs.mountpoint)
    return marray

def usage():
    uarray = {}
    for i in mountpoint():
        #create a dictionary with mountpoint as the key and the usage percentage as the value
        uarray[i] = psutil.disk_usage(i).percent
    return uarray

diskUsage = usage()

#Icinga errors
s = "SEVERE -"
c = "CRITICAL -"
w = "WARNING -"
o = "OK -"
u = "UNKNOWN -"

for key, value in diskUsage.items():
    if value == 100:
        print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(s,value,key))
        sys.exit(2)
    elif value >= 95 and value < 100:
        print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(c,value,key))
        sys.exit(2)
    elif value >= 92 and value < 95:
        print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(w,value,key))
        sys.exit(1)
    elif value < 92 and value > 0:
        print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(o,value,key))
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("UNKNOWN - Unable to pull file-system usage or a non int value was stored")
        sys.exit(3)
```

EDIT

The following did not work:

```
elif value < 92 and value > 0:
        print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(o,value,key))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.exit(0)

elif value < 92 and value > 0:
        print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(o,value,key), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(0)

elif value < 92 and value > 0:
            print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(o,value,key), flush=True)
            sys.exit(0)
```

This prints the full output:

```
elif value < 92 and value > 0:
            print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(o,value,key))
            SystemExit(0)
```

The desired output is with SystemExit(0):

```
OK - 1.8% used on /
OK - 35.7% used on /boot
```

The output i'm getting with sys.exit(0):

```
OK - 1.8% used on /
```

Comment: Try using ``print('message', file=sys.stderr)``. Does that change anything? It may be related to fact that ``stdout`` would be buffered and not necessarily written straight away. Alternatively add before the exit ``sys.stdout.flush()``. But why are you using ``sys.exit(0)`` in the first place, rather than using ``break`` and letting it drop out of the loop and then exit the script normally.

Comment: You should  use `print(thing, flush=True)`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i'm using the sys.exit(0) to capture the specific exit code for nagios to pick it up. I'm going to try the suggestions now and report back.

EDIT
This did not work:
elif value < 92 and value > 0:
        print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(o,value,key))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.exit(0)

Comment: I've added:

print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(o,value,key), file=sys.stderr)
print("{0} {1}% used on {2}".format(o,value,key), flush=True)
and sys.stdout.flush() between the print and sys.exit(0)

none of these worked

Comment: Add these to your question so the question and the things you've tried are clearer.

Comment: also, can you more precisely describe how and where the output is 'cut off'

Comment: Updated the question, thanks for the help.

Comment: And can you show what the SystemExit variant looks like?

Comment: it's not clear to me how this loop can possibly work when the first thing you do on a matching condition is just exit. For what you've shown it seems it's printing what one would expect

Comment: Then why does sys.exit(0) and SystemExit(0) provide different output?

Comment: because SystemExit is an exception, not a call - you're just instantiating the exception and not throwing it. that does nothing

Comment: so your program is working correctly, it's just logically flawed.

Comment: Read these things too - how to write a [MCVE] and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You'll get answers quicker - your question was incomplete and unanswerable.

Comment: Thank-you, what would be my solution to get the desired output while exiting with an exit code nagios can read?

Comment: That's a different question which you could try writing up separately and specifically. You can't have multiple exits for the same instance of a running program - that makes no sense. It may be the case what you really need is a script that runs for a single mount point and nagios is set up to invoke it for all the mounts it knows about. But again, you'd have to write up the particular problem you're having.

Comment: I see whats happening here, for every line in my output i'm doing sys.exit(0) so it always gets to the first line and then exits and doesn't continue. How would I let it print everything then exit?

Comment: You can put the exit at the end of your script. What you can't do, though, is have both multiple items AND multiple exit codes for multiple conditions per item. That's obviously impossible - you can only exit once.

Answer (score 5):

```
SystemExit(0)
```

That doesn't actually exit. It just builds an exception object and throws it away. You would need to `raise SystemExit(0)` to actually exit.

> When the status prints using sys.exit, the output from my print statement gets cut off to one line

Well, yeah. That's because you printed one line **and then exited**. Why are you calling `sys.exit` at all? If you want to set the process's exit code, call `sys.exit` once you're actually done.